# Unable to make S3DataSource work for Dragonfly Gem (Ruby 1.9.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

As per draganfly documentation here 
http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.DataStorage.html

I added following code to my initializer/draganfly.rb

```
enter code here

app = Dragonfly[:my_app_name]
app.datastore = Dragonfly::DataStorage::S3DataStore.new
app.datastore.configure do |c|
  c.bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
  c.access_key_id = 'salfjasd34u23'
  c.secret_access_key = '8u2u3rhkhfo23...'
  c.region = 'eu-west-1'                        # defaults to 'us-east-1'
  c.storage_headers = {'some' => 'thing'}       # defaults to {'x-amz-acl' => 'public-read'}
  c.url_scheme = 'https'                        # defaults to 'http'
end
```

I could not even start my server after adding code above. Here is the error I get in logs

```
Exiting
c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 
require: ca
not load such file -- fog (LoadError)
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-`enter code here`3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in
block in require
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in 

block in load_dependency'
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in
new_constants_in'
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in
load_dependency'
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in
require'
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dragonfly-0.9.9/lib/dragonfly/data_storage/s3data_store.rb:1:i
 `<top (required)>'
        from c:/rail_projects/c4fx2/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in
load'
        from c:/Connect/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in
block in load'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `gem 'fog'` to your Gemfile.

Worked for me when trying to get S3 working with Dragonfly in a Sinatra app.

From looking through the Dragonfly source code, I found the S3 data store [requires the fog gem](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/blob/master/lib/dragonfly/data_storage/s3data_store.rb#L1) and it wasn't being included in my Gemfile.lock. So I manually added it to the Gemfile.

Comment: worth noting.  i also had to add "gem dragonfly-s3_data_store"